# Como fazer um cronômetro continuar contando após fechar a página?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, apache

Preciso criar um cronômetro que é iniciado através de um *play*, mas queria uma solução, *que não seja somente por* **SESSION**, para deixá-lo contando mesmo que o cliente feche a janela ou caia sua internet, ou seja, que não seja dependente de `cache` ou `front`.

Como fazer isso com PHP, JavaScript e MySQL?

Comment: Continuar contando até quando? Se a página for reaberta exibe o mesmo cronômetro?

Comment: Exatamente! Ele conta até um pause ou stop! Podendo continuar quando pressionar pause e depois play. No entanto, nunca deve parar de contar quando estiver em 'play'.

Comment: Eu salvaria o timestamp no momento que o play é pressionado no banco e faria um cronômetro no `front-end`, se o usuário pressiona pause, calcula o tempo e salva este em outra tabela do banco. Se o usuário fechar a página e voltar, verifica se já existe um "timer" para ele no banco e trás o valor inicial para o cronômetro do front.

Comment: O problema é esse: "...Se o usuário fechar a página e voltar, verifica se já existe um "timer" para ele no banco e trás o valor inicial para o cronômetro do front."

Comment: Se for uma página qualquer em que o usuário não tenha um identificador único sempre, não vejo como isso é possível de ser feito. Ah não ser que o cronômetro não seja individual, mas sim algo relacionado a página, ae basta chamar um ajax no `onLoad`.

Comment: Mano, o usuário aperta play e é iniciado. A página só será fechada se: a internet cair, se ele fechar acidentalmente...Mas sempre ele deverá abrir a página e ver até onde está rodando o seu tempo a partir de seu play. E no fim ele clica em stop ou pause para poder parar. Talvez o lance seja como vc disse, verificar o time e calcular entre o início e o fim, mas se for de 3 dias ou mais?

Comment: Qual o problema de ser 3 dias ou mais? Play = salva timestamp, Pause = timestamp_atual - timestamp_salvo e armazena em uma tabela timer_total. Play pega o valor armazenado no timer_total e utiliza ele como valor inicial do cronômetro, Pause repete o calculo, porém agora incrementa no registro já salvo do timer_total.

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo como resposta?

Comment: Você precisa de compatibilidade com IE? Caso não precisar, pode usar algo baseado em localStorage

Comment: Como queres que o cliente se identifique? imagino que queres ter um cronometro por utilizador, existe algum login?

Comment: @Sergio, será um cronômetro para cada cliente, mas o foco da pergunta é sobre como continuar a contagem mesmo após um desligamento do computador até uma limpeza de cash...Enfim! Ajuda awe!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Considerando que o cronômetro deve armazenar a situação atual, proponho a seguinte estrutura:

- Ao acessar `timer.html`, uma requisição AJAX para `get_timer.php` pega o valor do cronômetro e a situação (pausado/rodando);
- Os botões "Iniciar" e "Pausar" enviam uma requisição AJAX para `grava_acao.php` que grava o *timestamp* e a ação atual com base na última ação gravada;
- Será possível gerar relatórios com os intervalos parados e rodando;

#### banco de dados

```
CREATE TABLE `timer` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
    `action` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
```

#### `timer.html`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
var format = function(seconds) {
    var tempos = {
        segundos: 60
    ,   minutos: 60
    ,   horas: 24
    ,   dias: ''
    };
    var parts = [], string = '', resto, dias;
    for (var unid in tempos) {
        if (typeof tempos[unid] === 'number') {
            resto = seconds % tempos[unid];
            seconds = (seconds - resto) / tempos[unid];
        } else {
            resto = seconds;
        }
        parts.unshift(resto);
    }
    dias = parts.shift();
    if (dias) {
        string = dias + (dias > 1 ? ' dias ' : ' dia ');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        parts[i] = ('0' + parts[i]).substr(-2);
    }
    string += parts.join(':');
    return string;
};
$(function(){
    var tempo = 0;
    var interval = 0;
    var timer = function(){
        $('.timer').html(format(++tempo));
    };
    $.post('get_timer.php', function(resp){
        $('button').text(resp.running ? 'Pausar' : 'Iniciar');
        tempo = resp.seconds;
        timer();
        if (resp.running) {
            interval = setInterval(timer, 1000);
        }
    });
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        var btn = this;
        btn.disabled = true;
        $.post('grava_acao.php', function(resp){
            btn.disabled = false;
            $(btn).text(resp.running ? 'Pausar' : 'Iniciar');
            if (resp.running) {
                timer();
                interval = setInterval(timer, 1000);
            } else {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<div class="timer">0 segundos</div>
<button>Iniciar</button>
```

#### `get_timer.php`

```
<?php
// definir no seu código
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $passwd);
$user_id = 1; // $_SESSION['user_id'];

$params = array(':user' => $user_id);
$stt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT `action`, `timestamp` FROM `timer` WHERE `user_id` = :user ORDER BY `id`');
$stt->execute($params);
$tempos = $stt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$seconds = 0;
$action = 'pause'; // sempre inicia pausado
foreach ($tempos as $tempo) {
    $action = $tempo['action'];
    switch ($action) {
        case 'start':
            $seconds -= $tempo['timestamp'];
            break;
        case 'pause':
            // para evitar erro se a primeira ação for pause
            if ($seconds !== 0) {
                $seconds += $tempo['timestamp'];
            }
            break;
    }
}
if ($action === 'start') {
    $seconds += time();
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
    'seconds' => $seconds,
    'running' => $action === 'start',
));
```

#### `grava_acao.php`

```
<?php
// definir no seu código
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $passwd);
$user_id = 1; // $_SESSION['user_id'];

$params = array(':user' => $user_id);
$stt1 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT `action` FROM `timer` WHERE `user_id` = :user ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1');
$stt1->execute($params);
$newAction = 'start';
if ($stt1->rowCount() && $stt1->fetchColumn() === 'start') {
    $newAction = 'pause';
}
$stt2 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `timer` (`user_id`, `action`, `timestamp`) VALUES (:user, :action, :time)');
$params[':action'] = $newAction;
$params[':time'] = time();
$stt2->execute($params);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array(
   'running' => $newAction === 'start',
)); // para atualizar status, no caso de concorrência
```

Comment: Esse é o rumo! Deve-se criar uma rotina para avaliar a situação pausado/rodando, para então gerar um cálculo matemático que trará o tempo do intervalo entre o início e o retorno à tela!

Comment: Duas informações: Sempre será uma contagem crescente e quando eu abrir a página, caso eu volte de uma possível queda/fechamento, o cronômetro deve startar/iniciar automaticamente! Mas você entrou no caminho mais correto que todos, até agora!

Comment: PERFEITO! NENHUMA FALHA OU COMPLICAÇÃO!

Comment: Sanção, último pedido: poderia definir como 00:00:00. No momento está 1 minutos 50 Segundos. OBRIGADO!

Comment: Sanção, quando passar 6 dias de play ele ficará 144 horas. Essa primeira casa de 00:00:00, contará 144:00:00?

Comment: quando há mais de 24h já muda pra dias: `6 dias 23:59:58` e `7 dias 00:00:38`, quando tem menos não aparece conforme condição `if (dias)`

Comment: SHOW!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 12):

Pode implementar um cronômetro *front-end* utilizando **JavaScript** onde ao clicar em *Play* inicia o timer, quando o usuário clicar em *Pause* ou fechar a janela deve-se então mandar um *Ajax* para o **PHP** atualizar o valor corrente do timer no banco de dados. Na próxima vez que a tela for aberta, faz-se então uma requisição *Ajax* ao **PHP** para que este retorne o valor corrente do timer que está salvo no banco.

**HTML:**

```
<body onload="restore_timer();">
    <form name="form">
        <input type="text" name="cronometro" value="00:00:00" />
        <br />
        <button type="button" onclick="timer(this); return false;">Play</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = form.cronometro.value;
    var hora = t.substring(0, 2);
    var minuto = t.substring(3, 5);
    var segundo = t.substring(6, 8);

    restore_timer = function() {
        send_ajax("get_time");
    }

    var interval;
    send_ajax = function(opt) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            async: "false",
            url: "timer.php",
            data: {"opt": opt}
        }).done(function(msg) {
            if (opt == "get_time") {
                if (msg.status == "started") {
                    $('button').html('Pause');
                    interval = setInterval('tempo()', 983);
                }
                form.cronometro.value = msg.time;
                t = msg.time;
                hora = t.substring(0, 2);
                minuto = t.substring(3, 5);
                segundo = t.substring(6, 8);
            }
        });
    }

    timer = function(obj) {
        var html = $(obj).html();
        if (html == 'Play') {
            interval = setInterval('tempo()', 983);
            send_ajax("start_timer");
            $(obj).html('Pause');
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
            send_ajax("save_time");
            $(obj).html('Play');
        }
    }

    tempo = function(){ 
       if (segundo < 59) {
          segundo++;
          if (segundo < 10)
             segundo = "0" + segundo;
       } else if (segundo == 59 && minuto < 59) {
          segundo = 0 + "0";
          minuto++;
          if (minuto < 10)
             minuto = "0" + minuto;
       }
       if (minuto == 59 && segundo == 59) {
          segundo = 0 + "0";
          minuto = 0 + "0";
          hora++;
          if (hora < 10)
             hora = "0" + hora;
       }
       form.cronometro.value = hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundo;
    }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
if ($_POST) {
    $opt = $_POST['opt'];

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "USUARIO";
    $password = "SENHA";
    $dbname = "BANCO_DE_DADOS";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    if ($opt == "get_time") {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM time_stamps WHERE id = 1";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        $old_time_stamp;
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $old_time_stamp = $row["time_stamp"];
            }

            $date = new DateTime();
            $time_stamp = $date->getTimestamp();

            echo json_encode(array("status" => "started", "time" => date('H:i:s', ($time_stamp - $old_time_stamp))));
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM timer WHERE id = 1";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo json_encode(array("time" => $row["time"]));
                }
            }
        }
    } elseif ($opt == "start_timer") {
        $date = new DateTime();
        $time_stamp = $date->getTimestamp();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO time_stamps VALUES (1, '{$time_stamp}')";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    } elseif ($opt == "save_time") {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM time_stamps WHERE id = 1";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        $old_time_stamp;
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $old_time_stamp = $row["time_stamp"];
            }
        }

        $sql = "DELETE FROM time_stamps WHERE id = 1";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        $date = new DateTime();
        $time_stamp = $date->getTimestamp();

        $new_time = explode(":", date('H:i:s', ($time_stamp - $old_time_stamp)));

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM timer WHERE id = 1";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        $old_time;
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $old_time = explode(":", $row["time"]);
            }
        }

        $hour = intval($old_time[0] + $new_time[0]);
        $minute = intval($old_time[1] + $new_time[1]);
        $second = intval($old_time[2] + $new_time[2]);
        while ($second >= 60) {
            $second = $second - 60;
            $minute++;
        }
        while ($minute >= 60) {
            $minute = $minute - 60;
            $hour++;
        }
        if ($second < 10)
            $second = "0" . strval($second);
        if ($minute < 10)
            $minute = "0" . strval($minute);
        if ($hour < 10)
            $hour = "0" . strval($hour);

        $time = "{$hour}:{$minute}:{$second}";

        $sql = "UPDATE timer SET time = '{$time}' WHERE id = 1";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

**DataBase:**

```
CREATE TABLE timer (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    time VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE time_stamps (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    time_stamp VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO timer values (1, "00:00:00");
```

> Neste exemplo tenho apenas um registro na tabela **timer**, se você
>   necessitar mais terá de mudar um pouco a lógica, mas acredito que isto
>   não será problema.

Segue [exemplo funcionando](http://luishenriique.zz.mu/cronometro/).

**Atenção:**
Não fiz nenhuma validação do valor transitado pelas requisições, se o usuário alterar o **HTML** na mão e der *Pause* vai mandar para o banco e salvar normalmente.

Comment: Mas a questão é DEIXAR ROLANDO e NÃO PAUSAR e continuar de onde FECHOU a janela.

Comment: Mano, muito obrigado pela força, mas ainda nao é isso. É quase isso.

Comment: @Lollipop por isso eu havia sugerido timestamp e não lembrava, quando fui fazer o exemplo agora pensei "assim é mais simples, não precisa do timestamp"... vou corrigir e daqui a pouco edito a resposta.

Comment: Veja uma situação: Iniciei o trabalho às 13:00, fechei a janela acidentalmente ou desliguei o PC às 13:30, 'e quando eu voltar', deve ser calculado o tempo que iniciei até o tempo que voltei, continuando a contagem automaticamente a partir das 13:30...Acho que o grande lançe é diferenciar o pause do "rodando", se eu não dei pause e tem um diferença, é pq ta rodando! Se há pausa, continua da pausa, como vc fez. Mas o buxo será pegar depois de uma pausa e play! PODE ATUALIZAR O EXEMPLO TBM? Abraço!

Comment: @Lollipop atualizei a resposta e o exemplo funcionando, tive que dar uma saída aqui e acabei demorando um pouco.

Comment: Mano, PARECE FUNCIONAR! Vou testar aqui e volto pra dar um prêmio! :)

Comment: O PHP ainda pode ser refatorado, fui escrevendo conforme fui pensando e repeti várias coisas, mas a ideia é essa.

Comment: Luis Henrique, não ta funcionando! Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined. NO JS!

Comment: A variavel `t` está nula, isso foi dentro do Ajax? Coloca um `console.log(msg)` e ve se o PHP retornou certo.

Comment: Deu certo, mas a tabela timer ta pegando as horas assim: 70:01:08. Isso pode ser um problema neh?

Comment: Depende o que é problema para você. A tabela timer é usada apenas para armazenar o tempo gasto e retornar para o javascript, no cálculo é usado sempre timestamp. Só tem que olhar o tamanho do campo  na tabela `timer` que se a hora virar 100 vai estourar eu acho.

Comment: Luis Henrique, por que o o código do seu exemplo, está diferente do código postado aqui? Não está funcionando iniciando de onde parou.

Comment: @Lollipop O nome da tabela é `time_stamps`. Corrigido.

Comment: Está dando um bug dos infernos! Quando atualizo a página, ele vai para 18:00:00

Comment: Até mesmo o seu exemplo, quando eu inicio dar tudo certo, mas quando pauso e dou play buga tbm. Ve awe mano!

Comment: @Lollipop caiu o cPanel do servidor aqui, não vou conseguir arrumar. Mas basicamente tens de fazer o seguinte: no `if($opt == "get_time")` onde ele verifica se existe um timestamp correndo (é o primeiro if) tens de fazer select na tabela timer e somar o valor, igual é feito no `save_time` lá em baixo. Só copiar e colar as coisas. Copie desde `$new_time = explode...` até `$time = "{$hour}..."`

Answer (score 4):

Desenvolvi uma solução com dados persistentes armazenados em arquivo e usando localStorage. Creio que esta solução atenderá o seu caso.

A solução é simples, o código ficou grande pois criei um gerenciador para testar o funcionamento.

Caso queira armazenar um banco de dados, basta mudar as funções de persistência da classe.

```
<?php

//
// Lib 
//

const CHRON_PATH  = '\path\to\data\\';

const CHRON_STOP  = 0x00;
const CHRON_PAUSE = 0x01;
const CHRON_PLAY  = 0x03;

class PersistentChronometer {
    // fields

    private $_id;
    private $_elapsed;
    private $_status;
    private $_statustime;

    // construtor privado

    private function __construct() {}

    // propriedades

    function __get($prop) {
        switch($prop) {
        case 'id':
            return $this->_id;
        case 'status':
            return $this->_status;
        case 'elapsed':
            $elapsed = $this->_elapsed;

            if ($this->_status == CHRON_PLAY)
                $elapsed += max(microtime(true) - $this->_statustime, 0);

            return $elapsed;
        }
    }

    // comandos

    public function play() {
        if($this->_status == CHRON_PLAY)
            return;

        $this->_statustime = microtime(true);
        $this->_status = CHRON_PLAY;
    }

    public function pause() {
        if($this->_status != CHRON_PLAY)
            return;

        $time = microtime(true);

        $this->_elapsed += max($time - $this->_statustime, 0);

        $this->_statustime = microtime(true);
        $this->_status = CHRON_PAUSE;
    }

    public function stop() {
        if($this->_status == CHRON_STOP)
            return;

        $this->_statustime = microtime(true);
        $this->_elapsed = 0;
        $this->_status = CHRON_STOP;
    }

    // persistência

    public static function create() {
        $chron = new PersistentChronometer();
        $chron->_statustime = microtime(true);
        $chron->_elapsed = 0;
        $chron->_status = CHRON_STOP;

        $i = 0;
        while (true) {
            $chron->_id = ((int)$chron->_statustime) . '$' . $i++;

            $fname = CHRON_PATH . $chron->_id . '.chron';
            if(file_exists($fname)) 
                continue;
            $f = fopen($fname, 'w');
            fwrite($f, $chron->serialize());
            fclose($f);
            break;
        } 

        return $chron;
    }

    public static function load($id) {
        $fname = CHRON_PATH . $id . '.chron';

        if(!file_exists($fname))
            return false;
        $f = fopen($fname, 'r');
        $chron = PersistentChronometer::unserialize(fread($f, 255));
        fclose($f);

        return $chron;
    }

    public function save() {
        $fname = CHRON_PATH . $this->_id . '.chron';
        $f = fopen($fname, 'w');
        ftruncate($f, 0);
        fwrite($f, $this->serialize());
        fclose($f);
    }

    public function delete() {
        $fname = CHRON_PATH . $this->_id . '.chron';
        unlink($fname);
    }

    public function serialize() {
        return json_encode(array(
            'id' => $this->_id,
            'elapsed' => $this->_elapsed,
            'status' => $this->_status,
            'statustime' => $this->_statustime
        ));
    }

    public static function unserialize($string) {
        $data = json_decode($string);

        $chron = new PersistentChronometer();
        $chron->_id = $data->id;
        $chron->_elapsed = $data->elapsed;
        $chron->_status = $data->status;
        $chron->_statustime = $data->statustime;

        return $chron;
    }
}

//
// Comandos
//

if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
    switch($_GET['action']) {
    case 'play':
        if(isset($_GET['id'])
          && (($chron = PersistentChronometer::load($_GET['id'])) !== false)) {
            $chron->play();
            $chron->save();
        }
        break;
    case 'pause':
        if(isset($_GET['id'])
          && (($chron = PersistentChronometer::load($_GET['id'])) !== false)) {
            $chron->pause();
            $chron->save();
        }
        break;
    case 'stop':
        if(isset($_GET['id'])
          && (($chron = PersistentChronometer::load($_GET['id'])) !== false)) {
            $chron->stop();
            $chron->save();
        }
        break;
    case 'new':
        PersistentChronometer::create();
        break;
    case 'delete':
        if(isset($_GET['id'])
          && (($chron = PersistentChronometer::load($_GET['id'])) !== false)) {
            $chron->delete();
        }
        break;
    case 'get':
        if(isset($_GET['id'])
          && (($chron = PersistentChronometer::load($_GET['id'])) !== false)) {

            $data = new stdClass();
            $data->id = $chron->id;
            $data->elapsed = $chron->elapsed;
            $data->status = $chron->status;
            $data->result = true;

            echo json_encode($data);
        } else {
            echo '{"result": false}';
        }

        return;
    }
}

//
// Output
//

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var cEl = $('#chron');
            if(!window.localStorage)
                cEl.text('Para esta solução é necessário o uso de localStorage. Mas também podem ser utilizados cookies ou variaveis de sessão!!!');
            else {
                var id = localStorage.getItem("chron-id");

                if(!id)
                    cEl.text('Nenhum cronômetro definido!');
                else {
                    loadChronometer(id);
                    cEl.text('Aguarde...');
                }
            }
        });

        function setChronometer(id) {
            localStorage.setItem("chron-id", id);
            loadChronometer(id);
        }

        function loadChronometer(id) {
            var status = {
                <?php echo CHRON_STOP ?>: 'Parado',
                <?php echo CHRON_PLAY ?>: 'Executando',
                <?php echo CHRON_PAUSE ?>: 'Interrompido'
            };
            var cEl = $('#chron');
            $.getJSON('?action=get&id=' + id, null, function(data) {
                if(data.result)
                    cEl.text(
                        'ID: ' + data.id + "\n" +
                        'Estado: ' + status[data.status] + "\n" +
                        'Tempo (seg): ' + data.elapsed + "\n"
                    ).append(
                        '<a href="javascript:setChronometer(\'' + data.id + '\')">Atualizar</a> | ' +
                        (data.status == <?php echo CHRON_STOP ?> ? '' : '<a href="?action=stop&id=' + data.id + '">Parar</a> | ') +
                        (data.status == <?php echo CHRON_PLAY ?> ? '' : '<a href="?action=play&id=' + data.id + '">Executar</a> | ') +
                        (data.status != <?php echo CHRON_PLAY ?> ? '' : '<a href="?action=pause&id=' + data.id + '">Interromper</a> | ') +
                        '<a href="javascript:setChronometer(null)">Remover</a>' 
                    );
                else
                    cEl.text('Nenhum cronômetro definido!');
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Cronômetro padrão</h1>

<pre id="chron" style="white-space: pre"></pre>


<h1>Gerenciador</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Estado</td>
        <td colspan="5">Comandos</td>
        <td>Tempo (seg)</td>
    </thead>
<?php

$files = scandir(CHRON_PATH);
$chrons = array();
foreach($files as $file) {
    if (substr($file, -6) == '.chron')
        $chrons[] = PersistentChronometer::load(substr($file, 0, -6));
}

$status = array(
    CHRON_STOP  => 'Parado',
    CHRON_PLAY  => 'Executando',
    CHRON_PAUSE => 'Interrompido'
);

foreach($chrons as $chron) {
    $td = array();
    $td[] = $chron->id;
    $td[] = $status[$chron->status];

    $td[] = $chron->status == CHRON_STOP ? '' : '<a href="?action=stop&id='. $chron->id .'">Parar</a>';
    $td[] = $chron->status == CHRON_PLAY ? '' : '<a href="?action=play&id='. $chron->id .'">Executar</a>';
    $td[] = $chron->status != CHRON_PLAY ? '' : '<a href="?action=pause&id='. $chron->id .'">Interromper</a>';
    $td[] = '<a href="?action=delete&id='. $chron->id .'">Destruir</a>';
    $td[] = '<a href="javascript:setChronometer(\''. $chron->id .'\')">Padrão</a>';
    $td[] = $chron->elapsed;
    echo '<tr id="cron-'. $chron->id .'"><td>'. implode('</td><td>', $td) .'</td></tr>';
}

?>
</table>
<a href="?action=new">Novo cronômetro</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O uso será por usuário. Como diferenciaria um usuário do outro? Belo código!

Comment: Obrigado. Fiz esse código apenas para atender sua necessidade, pois percebi nos comentário anteriores que estava havendo muita confusão sobre sua real necessidade. Como pode perceber no código, você consegue obter as informações de um determinado cronômetro pela requisição de `?action=get&id={id}`. Mas editar a resposta para uma solução mais específica.

Comment: Na realidade, não tem muito segredo, basta vincular seu usuário ao ID de um cronômetro criado com a função PHP PersistentChronometer::create(). A classe é bem simples e muito versátil, se analisar o código do pequeno gerenciador que acompanha, logo vai entender e poderá implementar no seu projeto.

Answer (score 2):

Creio que se você pode usar os atributos do **localStorage()** para chegar em uma solução! O localStorage é uma função implementada em browsers mais atualizados (óbvil que não o IE) onde o browser salva uma informação sobre aquele domínio acessado dentro de uma variável, assim você pode pegar e salvar informações na variável quando a página for fechada e quando abrir a mesma, buscar o valor inicial do click e com base nisso continuar a contar o cronômetro. Os registros da variável só são excluídos quando reescrevidos ou então quando o cache do browser é limpo.

Comment: Vejo um problema nisso caso o usuário possa acessar o sistema de outro navegador/máquina.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia armazenar no cookie ou via Web SQL o valor inicial, o timestamp onde iniciou o seu cronometro. Ao sair da pagina o valor estaria salvo no navegador do usuário, e caso já tenha algum dado gravado no navegador ele continuaria de onde parou. Também seria interessante armazenar o estado do seu cronometro (rodando, pausado).

Comment: Isso seria mais seguro, em termos de perca de dados, do que salvar via banco de dados no seu próprio servidor?

Comment: Vejo um problema nisso caso o usuário possa acessar o sistema de outro navegador/máquina.

Comment: Então.............

Comment: Não, não seria mais seguro, mas poderia ser mais eficiente em um primeiro momento. O que você pode fazer é trabalhar das duas formas, no navegador e no servidor, e de tempos em tempos sincronizar ambos.

Comment: @LucasPolo, não sei se você viu mas já tinha trazido esta solução ao citar o localStorage() na resposta acima

Answer (score 1):

Se você não precisa se preocupar com o usuário alterando suas variáveis no js aconselho a seguir a solução do @LucasPolo, caso contrário faria algo assim:

Ao iniciar o cronômetro, o js executa uma requisição ao servidor que salva no banco de dados o timestamp atual (obtido através do php, não do js).

O js continua rodando o cronômetro e a cada intervalo determinado de tempo, ou quando o usuário voltar ao navegador (após tê-lo fechado)0 o js faz uma requisição ao servidor para obter o tempo decorrido desde o início.

Comment: Isso awe, man!!