# Contador em PHP

Tags: php, html, algoritmo

Gostaria de estar fazendo um contator em PHP no qual eu possa estar definindo um tempo para estar aparecendo o próximo número. Por exemplo, aparece o número 1 e depois aparece o número 2 substituindo o número 1. Seria na especie de um cronometro.

Sabem me informar algum função que faça essa substituição de números e outra para eu determinar o tempo que aparece o próximo número?

Agradeço dês de já.

Comment: [Como fazer um cronômetro continuar contando após fechar a página?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/62990/5878) Se não for duplicata, com certeza é algo para você começar os estudos.

Comment: E um cronometro em JS não serve para o seu caso ? Se for o caso já tem por ai várias respostas com exemplos disso

Answer (score 1):

Bom, você precisa fazer o contador em php, algo assim:

```
<?php 
     $num =  isset($_REQUEST["n"]) ? $_REQUEST["n"] : 0; //recebe o numero pela url
     $num++; //inclementa o numero
?>
```

Depois vem a parte de JavaScript (coloque isso no final do arquivo php):

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){ //faz um teporizador
       location.href = location.href + "?n=<?=$num?>"; //atualiza a página com o $num novo
   }, 1000); //1000 milisegundos, ou seja 1s
</script>
```